# How to handle the context of this two pages? (Store information securely to show in the next page)

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to have a context like below, first there is a page where the user select the quantities that he wants for each ticket type, then the user click in next and he goes to a page that shows a summary of the request and there is also a form so the user introduce his name, email, etc, then the user click next and selects the payment type, then selects next and its the payment page.
[image]

Im trying to have the context of the first two pages. I have a details.blade.php for the first page that shows the ticket type, the select menu and the price of the ticket type:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('congress.registration', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">

                <select name={{ $ticket->title }}>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

This is working fine.

**Doubt:** My doubt is when "Next" button is clicked how to create the context for the second page. That is, securely store the selected quantities for each type and the price of each type and redirect user to the next page where there is the request summary. The summary as it is in the image has the quantity for each ticket type and also the price of each ticket type.

I created a RegistrationController and storeTypes() method for this context but I dont know how to securely store the selected quantities for each type by the user and also the prices.

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function storeTypes(Request $request){
        $selectedTypes = $request->type;
        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTtypes);
    }

}
```

Note:

- When "Next" is clicked in the first page, we are coming from the congress page so there is the congress_id and there is one to many relationship between congress and ticketTypes.
- The user can´t change the price, but in the first page as it is in the image it appears the price inside a `<span>`. And the user can change this price in source code and then in the next page the price appears incorrect, I dont know how to properly handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the data to session to make it persist between page loads.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#using-the-session

Create a controller function and a route for each step: One just for displaying the initial form; Other for processing it's submission (save data to session and redirect to next step); And other for displaying the next page (and so on).

You can save data from an input field to session using

```
$request->session->put('quantity', $request->input('quantity');
```

Then you retrieve it using.

```
$request->session->get('quantity');
```

Comment: Thanks, but also how to store the price? But that way with sessions is not the same as it is in the question  with "        $selectedTypes = $request->type;
        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTtypes);". And like that the user can change for example the quantities in source code and add for example "1000000" quantity and the controller will store that in session and return that to the next page?

Comment: I don't think `$request->type` would return anything. What's happening with your code when you run it?
Looks like you lack a bit of understanding on how sessions and sending form data works. Take a look at these stuff, it will help you 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data
http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php
Just altering the source code in the summary page won't alter the data in the session. To alter the data in the session, the user would have to go back to first page and submit the form again.

Comment: Thanks, but for example if the user in the first page in the source code change the quantity for a specific ticket type to "100000" and then click "Next" in the controller I cant store the selected quantities by the user in the session, but it will store for that specific type the value "100000" which is incorrect.

Comment: You add to the form only data you want to be manipulated by the user. In this case, only the quantity. Altering any other element in the page will  not affect data in the server.